# configuring subversion client to use 3-way conflict markers

Tags: svn

Can anyone let me know how to configure subversion client to use 3-way conflict markers ? The resultant conflict file will show conflicts similar to the one copied below - with working section, merge-left section and merge-right section (so that one doesn't have to refer to merge-left.xxx and merge-right.yyy file ).  We are using subversion 1.6 client. Thanks.

<<<<<< .working

code

||||||| .merge-left.rxxx

code

=======

code

>>>>>>> .merge-right.ryyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to modify the source.  This is unfortunately hardcoded.  However, you're not the first that have asked for this.  We should probably make this a configuration option.

In **subversion/libsvn_wc/merge.c** find the function named `do_text_merge` and modify the following call:

```
  SVN_ERR(svn_diff_file_output_merge2(ostream, diff,
                                      left, detranslated_target, right,
                                      left_marker,
                                      target_marker,
                                      right_marker,
                                      "=======", /* separator */
                                      svn_diff_conflict_display_modified_latest ,
                                      pool));
```

What you want to change is `svn_diff_conflict_display_modified_latest` to `svn_diff_conflict_display_modified_original_latest`.  There are of course [other potential values documented in our API](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.6/svn__diff_8h.html#a86f960b73a7a17393e7fd071cfb48655).